# Strange Angular pattern, passing yet undefined functions to be defined by children

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been encountering this pattern a lot at my company where there will be a directive that passing an undefined property on its own scope down to a child directive where it is then defined (usually making use of properties on the child's scope) and later used not just by the parent, but also by the parent's other children. I have been sort of racking my brain about what to do with this, since there is all kinds of reference to the child scope.

Is this a good pattern? common? I feel like it is bad, but I am pretty new to angular and hesitant to call it out.

e.g.

```
<parent>
  <child-one function="foo"></child-one>
  <child-two function="foo"></child-two>
</parent>
```

only ref to foo in parent or childTwo directive will be to call it and definition is in childOne's directive.

```
.directive('parent', [function () {
  return {
    link: function ($scope) {
      $scope.someOtherFunction = function () {
        $scope.foo();
      }
    }
  };
}])

.directive('childOne', [function () {
  return {
    scope: { foo: '=' },
    link: function ($scope) {
      $scope.foo = function () {
        // do something
      }
    }
  };
}])

.directive('childTwo', [function () {
  return {
    scope: { foo: '=' },
    link: function ($scope) {
      $scope.someTotallyDifferentFunction = function () {
        $scope.foo();
      }
    }
  };
}])
```

Comment: It is truly evil. Two-way binding is for passing data between scopes, not behaviour. The proper implementation depends on what `foo` does, but it most certainly shouldn't abuse `=` binding the way it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mispractice, and should be avoided since it violates part of the SOLID priciples, specifically the first one: "Single Responsibility". Why a sibling needs to use a function of another sibling!? If both share functionality, it should be in a 'common' library, available to both.